# Julia package version control in production environment

Tags: version-control, julia

How do you do version control in Julia if you want to use it in a production environment. That is, most of the Julia packages and Julia itself have a 0.3.10 or similar version number, so you should be prepared for major interface changes in the (near) future, and especially when the first digit flips from 0 to 1.

My package status look something like this:

```
julia> Pkg.status()
4 required packages:
 - DataFrames                    0.6.9
 - Gadfly                        0.3.13
 - Jewel                         1.0.5
 - Mongo                         0.1.3
44 additional packages:
 - ArrayViews                    0.6.3
 - BinDeps                       0.3.15
 - Calculus                      0.1.10
 - Codecs                        0.1.4
 - Color                         0.4.7
 - Compat                        0.6.0
 - Compose                       0.3.13
 - Contour                       0.0.7
 - DataArrays                    0.2.17
 - DataStructures                0.3.12
etc...
```

It is recommended that you use `Pkg.update()` often so you have the most recent patches on all your packages.

If you need to update a package because of these patches or you need to use a new feature, you may break your code and there may also be dependencies between various packages, too.

Julia may be a mature enough language that does not have serious version-control problems, but I feel the need to poll the opinion of Julia users about their experience.

Answer (score 9):

In a production environment you should not be using `Pkg.update()` often, or at least not without testing in a non-production environment first. This is true for every packaging system, not just Julia.
For Julia in particular, I would also recommend establishing a set of versions that work for you, then use appropriate lower and upper bounds in your `REQUIRE` file.

For example, suppose `JuMP` 0.9.2 works well for me, as does Gadfly 0.4.2. I would probably do something like the following in `~/.julia/v0.3/REQUIRE`:

```
JuMP 0.9.2 0.10
Gadfly 0.4.2 0.5
```

This way, if I run `Pkg.update()` I will get `0.9.3` and `0.4.3` if they come out, but I won't be automatically upgraded to `JuMP 0.10`. Of course, this only works if you trust package maintainers to use version numbers sensibly, which is a serious problem especially when they are pre-`1.0`.

Answer (score 5):

The `DeclarativePackages.jl` package (https://github.com/rened/DeclarativePackages.jl) allows you to specify exactly which versions of each package you want to use for each project: it starts Julia with exactly those versions of those packages available. This sounds like it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Hmm. That sound something really useful seeing all the Julia package misery as a new user to Julia. Sooner or later the creators of Julia should start thinking about a serious package management system, system that people started writing for various javascript libraries/frameworks for example.

Comment: Haven't heard of much "package misery". `Pkg` works much very much like `npm` and `pip` in many respects, with a lot of the differences being conscious decisions.